# Disable right click for Shadowbox.js

Tags: javascript, right-click, shadowbox

I'm currently using [Shadowbox.js](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/) to my gallery and I want to disable the right click when the visitor views the image in full size. How can I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Comment: I want to force the visitor to hit the download link for the image instead of save the image from the context menu. In that way I can handle every downloads and have more control over who have the image on their computer.

Comment: people can still look at the source code. and they don't like to be controlled. at least that obviously

Comment: You can disable it completely fairly easily: [Jquery/JS prevent right click menu in browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920221/jquery-js-prevent-right-click-menu-in-browsers)

Comment: @Alp: Many users don't know that they can look in the source code and take the image from there. I know that and they will be notified that their action will be logged once they click on the download link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following to specifically target [Shadowbox.js](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/) and leave the context menu intact on the rest of the page.

### jQuery 1.7+

```
$(function(){
    $('#sb-wrapper').on('contextmenu', function(){return false;});
});
```

### jQuery 1.6

```
$(function(){
    $('#sb-wrapper').live('contextmenu', function(){return false;});
});
```

### Native

```
//Should be executed as part of the window.onload method 
document.getElementById('sb-wrapper').oncontextmenu = function(){return false;}
```

### Demo

Execute the Native statement in the Chrome's console on http://www.shadowbox-js.com/

Comment: Thanks! The native solution worked better than the jQuery for some reason :)

Comment: Glad it worked! Could be your version of jQuery. I added some more clarification. I wasn't able to test though and you can always use [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) if both of the above fail.

Comment: I'm glad too :) I have the latest jQuery version (1.7.2).

Comment: I tested the jQuery variant of your solution and `live` worked perfectly. Thanks once again!