# Javascript event.button returns no value for right click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contextmenu, right-click

I am trying to create a custom context menu for my website. I have been unable to accomplish the first task, which would be capturing and preventing the default of a right click. I have tried the following:

```
function rclick(event) {
if (event==null) {event = window.event;}

var target = event.target != null ? event.target : event.srcElement;
        console.log(event.button);
if ((event.button == 2 || event.button==4 || (event.keyCode==17 && event.button ==0)) && target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'a') {//1 and not internet explorer - middle
    event.preventDefault();
    var scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop ? document.body.scrollTop :
    document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    var scrollLeft = document.body.scrollLeft ? document.body.scrollLeft :
    document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    document.getElementById("context").style.left = event.clientX + scrollLeft +'px';
    document.getElementById("context").style.top = event.clientY + scrollTop +'px';
    document.getElementById("context").style.display = 'block';
}

}
```

I have attached the event to all anchor elements with:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){$("a").bind("click",function() {rclick(event);});});
```

When I left-click on an a element, event.button gives me '0'. But when I right click, the browser context menu appears, and the event does not fire (the value will not appear in the console log. How can I capture the right click and prevent default?

----update----

I have added this line:

```
$(document).ready(function(){$('a').on("contextmenu", function(evt) {evt.preventDefault();});});
```

and that successfully prevented the context menu from appearing on right click on anchor elements. However, when I add these lines to my mousedown function:

```
 document.getElementById("conmen").style.left = event.clientX + scrollLeft +'px';                                     
 document.getElementById("conmen").style.top = event.clientY + scrollTop +'px';
 document.getElementById("conmen").style.display = 'block';
```

then the context menu appears on top of the custom context menu I have designed. Why would these lines make the browser context menu appear?

Comment: I believe your question has been answered here: [Jquery/JS prevent right click menu in browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920221/jquery-js-prevent-right-click-menu-in-browsers).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making custom right-click context menus for my web-app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495626/making-custom-right-click-context-menus-for-my-web-app)

Comment: Thanks Misty Fowler that was helpful - i missed that one. I managed to stop the event default with some code from there - but still couldnt capture the right click.  @stefano has provided the missing piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```
$(document).ready(function(){$("a").bind("mousedown",function(event) {

var btn = event.which;

if(btn == 1) {

    //Left Button

} else if (btn == 2) {

    //Middle Button

} else if (btn == 3) {

    //Right Button

}

})});
```

https://api.jquery.com/mousedown/

Comment: You can use a switch as well ;)

Comment: do you know if event.which will give the same values for left/middle/right across browsers and platforms - if so it's an immense improvement over event.button.

Comment: as the documentation say : "Not all browsers support this property (Internet Explorer uses button instead), but jQuery normalizes the property so that it is safe to use in any browser".

Comment: Hi @stefano, sorry to trouble you again, but I described above a problem which has arisen with the mousedown function - can you understand why it is happening?

Comment: Nevermind - I just needed to put those statements in the on contextmenu function instead of having a separate mousedown function