# How to prevent default right click on canvas containing image

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, right-click

I have a canvas and I display an image inside it. I have attached a jquery event to it, like this:

```
$("#mycanvas").mousedown(function(e) {
    //Do something
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

I would expect this code to do my operations and to prevent default browser behavior. The former is fulfilled, however, the latter, namely, default behavior prevention does not happen. The event runs though. I wonder how could I prevent showing that menu you can see on the image upon right-click:

[image]

Comment: Be aware that while preventing right click will stop the context menu appearing, I can still see the URL to the image and download it through the DOM viewer/dev tools. The old adage applies - if it's viewable online, anyone can take it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, that's ok, I just want the user not to see that menu, everything else is nice.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920221/jquery-js-prevent-right-click-menu-in-browsers

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [contextmenu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/contextmenu):

```
$("#mycanvas").contextmenu(function(e) {
    //Do something
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```